# Passing CoreData object between VC’s

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am looking for some clarification and hope someone can help me understand.

My app is completely built programmatically and I’m not using storyboards at all, therefore I don’t have any segues.

I’m trying to pass a CoreData object from one VC to another via the `didSelectRowAt` method of a tableView.

I have the object being returned at the indexPath correctly, but appear to have issues in passing that object across to the new VC.

In this code extract, my only concern at the moment is to get the CoreData object passed so I can then access all of the associated data.

ie:  when the place is passed, I would like to print the name, latitude, longitude.

This will allow me to continue on with the app and use that data in the new VC.

Thanks in advance.

```
//    PlacesVC

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let placeOnMap = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        let destVC = MapVC()
        destVC.placePassed = placeOnMap
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)

        print(placeOnMap.placeName!)
    }

//    MapVC

import UIKit

class MapVC: UIViewController {

    var placePassed = PlaceEntity?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .green

    //  print(placePassed.placeName!)
    //  print(placePassed.latitude!)
    //  print(placePassed.longitude!)

    }
}
```

***Updated Information***

In the `PlacesVC()`, the following is occurring.

If I option click on the let `placeOnMap`, I get…

`Declaration: let placeOnMap: PlaceEntity`

The line of code…  `destVC.placePassed = placeOnMap`, gives the following error.

*Cannot assign value of type 'PlaceEntity' to type 'PlaceEntity?.Type'*

On the `MapVC()`

If I option click on the `placePassed` var, I get…

`Declaration: let placePassed: PlaceEntity?.Type`

Also, this line of code…  `var placePassed = PlaceEntity?`, gives the following error.

*Expected member name or constructor call after type name*

and If I uncomment the print statement on the destVC, this error pops up…

*Type 'PlaceEntity?' has no member 'placeName'*

I believe my issues are something to do with the way I am setting the var on the receiving VC because it is adding the .Type to the declared var.

This is the part I am not understanding.  Thanks

Comment: Can’t see a problem in the code; what issues are you experiencing?

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for your response.  I have updated the question with additional information.

Comment: Swap the = for a colon thus `var placePassed : PlaceEntity?`.  Using a colon means "placePassed is a variable of type 'PlaceEntity'"; using = means "placePassed is *the* type 'PlaceEntity'" - hence the .Type which is causing the problems.

Comment: @pbasdf  Thank you very much.  That did the trick.  When learning, it's so frustrating to be close, but not getting it right.